# UIAlertView Crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am getting this below exception while prompt to user

```
0  CoreFoundation   __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1  libobjc.A.dylib  objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation   -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 202
3  CoreFoundation   ___forwarding___ + 706
4  CoreFoundation   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5  UIKit            -[_UIModalItem setMessage:] + 40
6  UIKit            -[_UIModalItem initWithTitle:message:otherButtonTitles:completion:delegate:] + 102
7  UIKit            +[_UIModalItem modalItemWithType:title:message:buttonTitles:completion:] + 76
8  UIKit            -[UIAlertView _modalItemForNeueCompatibility] + 362
9  UIKit            -[UIAlertView popupAlertAnimated:animationType:atOffset:] + 56
10 UIKit            -[UIAlertView popupAlertAnimated:animationType:] + 34
```

I written Alert view code in a method in one of my utility class

```
+(void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString*)title message:(NSString*)msg cancelButtonTitle:(NSString*)canceltitle confirmBtnTitle:(NSString*)cnftitle andTag:(int)alertTag  andDelegate:(id)ref{

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:ref cancelButtonTitle:canceltitle otherButtonTitles:cnftitle, nil];
    alertView.tag = alertTag;
    [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: I implemented the identical code and it works fine. Do you have a breakpoint set up for objective-c exceptions?

Comment: Does `ref` exist when the alert is dismissed?

Comment: Actually I will pass `ref` when I need to perform any action. Otherwise `ref` will be `nil` means no delegate.

Comment: @Mike It working for me also. But some time it getting crashed, and I am unable to find out the reason.

Comment: Yes, When I need need action based on prompt, I have delegate method of UIAlertView.

Comment: Did you add an objective-c exception breakpoint?

Comment: Yes objective-c exception breakpoint added. But not helpful :(

Comment: What is the exception message? The stack trace indicates that an unrecognised selector has been invoked. The object and selector from the exception message will provide vital clues

Comment: Does enabling NSZombies teach you anything?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their comment. But crash happens due to another reason but some how "Crashlytics" showing me this log.

Answer (score -1):

You must show the alert view from the main thread. If this piece of code can potentially be called from any other queue or thread, wrap it in a call to dispatch_async:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:ref cancelButtonTitle:canceltitle otherButtonTitles:cnftitle, nil];
    alertView.tag = alertTag;
    [alertView show];
});
```

Comment: The OP did not state in his question or in the comments that he was calling from a background thread, instead he receives an unrecognized selector exception which, in the case, is independent of the thread.